# DISTINCT in JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, distinct

I have a question in Oracle SQL.

To simplify my problem, let's say I have two tables:

```
TAB1:                TAB2:
Usr  Fruit            Fruit  Calories
1    A                A      100
1    A                B      200
1    A                C      150
1    C                D      400
1    C                E      50
2    A
2    A
2    E
```

It's important that there are double entries in TAB1.
Now I want to know the calories for usr 1. But by joining both tables

```
SELECT TAB2.calories from TAB1
JOIN TAB2 ON TAB1.Fruit = TAB2.Fruit
WHERE TAB1.Usr = 1;
```

I get double results for the double entries. I could of course use distinct in the header, but is there a possibility to distinct the values (to A and C) directly in the join? I am sure that would improve my (much larger) performance.

Thanks!

Comment: If the user eats/uses the fruit three times, doesn't s/he three times the calories?

Comment: you mean if i eat 800g chocolade in 4 potions, only 200g count?

Comment: **Why** is it important to have repetitive entries in TAB1? If usr 1 has fruit A 3 times, then the calories are 300. Is an accurate result is also "important"?

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big fan of the semi-join.  For tables this small, it won't matter, but for larger tables it can make a big difference:

```
select
  tab2.calories
from tab2
where exists (
  select null
  from tab1
  where tab1.fruit = tab2.fruit and tab1.usr = 1
)
```

Comment: That is a great solution I have to say! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try as this:

```
SELECT TAB2.calories 
 from (select distinct usr, fruit from TAB1) as T1
        JOIN TAB2 ON T1.Fruit = TAB2.Fruit
WHERE T1.Usr = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do distinct before the join

```
select sum(tab2.calories) as TotalCalories
from (select distinct tab1.*
      from tabl
     ) t1 join
     tab2
     on t1.fruit = tab2.fruit
where t1.user = 1;
```

Also, to add the values, use an aggregation function.

Answer (score 1):

since you select nothing in tabA and maybe you have some usefull index, i'd go for an `IN` instead of the join

```
SELECT TAB2.calories 
FROM TAB2
WHERE TAB2.Fruit IN ( SELECT TAB1.Fruit FROM TAB1 WHERE TAB1.Usr = 1)
```

i'm pretty sure this one will take longer but you can still try:

```
SELECT TAB2.calories 
FROM TAB2
WHERE TAB2.Fruit IN ( SELECT DISTINCT TAB1.Fruit FROM TAB1 WHERE TAB1.Usr = 1)
```

Comment: I am told (but don't know first-hand) that the first way is preferred, as the CBO will optimize that into a semi-join if it needs to, thus eliminating the grouping/sorting associated with a distinct.  Results-wise, they will definitely yield identical results

Comment: @Hambone yeah my comment wasn't that clear. changed it.

Comment: Maybe this is a faux-pas, but I am curious why this answer was down-voted.  The solution will work, was properly explained and is efficient.  If someone can explain, I'd like to know, for my own education, what is wrong with the response.